# JavaScript on local scoping (very noob)

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to learn JavaScript and I'm stuck with scoping.

```
var payments = function () {
    var invoice = {};
    return {
        init: function (Obj) {
            invoice = Obj;
        },
        invoice : invoice
    };
}();
```

I call `payments.init({foo:bar})`. Then if I call `payments.invoice` it returns `undefined`. But the `init` function *should* search for the outer variable `invoice` when called. What am I doing wrong?

I come from PHP and the OOP in JavaScript is driving me crazy.

Comment: It's a good idea to use Capitalized names for classes only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the `invoice` property is assigned by value, not by reference (JS does not have assignments by reference).

Then, when you change the value of the variable `invoice`, the value of the property `invoice` is not magically updated.

Instead of storing the value of `invoice` in a data property, you can try using a method which reads the variable `invoice`:

```
var payments = function () {
  var invoice = {};
  return {
    init: function (obj) { invoice = obj; },
    invoice: function() { return invoice; }
  }
}();
payments.init({foo: "bar"});
payments.invoice(); // {foo: "bar"}
```

Or using a getter property:

```
var payments = function () {
  var invoice = {};
  return {
    init: function (obj) { invoice = obj; },
    get invoice() { return invoice; }
  }
}();
payments.init({foo: "bar"});
payments.invoice; // {foo: "bar"}
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because the `invoice` property of the returned object still points to the initial object. You've changed the object the `invoice` variables points to, but not the module object.

Try something like this:

```
var payments = function () {
    var module = {
        init: function (Obj) {
            module.invoice = Obj;
        },
        invoice: null
    };
    return module;
}();
```

Comment: That would be the same of 
`var payments = function () {
    var invoice = {};
    return {
        init: function (Obj) {
            this.invoice = Obj;
        },
        invoice : null
    };
}();`

Right?

Comment: @RiccardoBarbotti No, because it reassigns the property of the returned module object, rather than just a local variable scoped to the function.

Answer (score 0):

it like this:

```
var invoice={a:1}
var payments={
    init:function(obj){
        invoice=obj;
        console.log(invoice);
    },
    invoice:invoice
};
payments.init({foo:'bar'});//{foo:'bar'}
console.log(payments.invoice)//{a:1}
```